# How to avoid redirecting in css files with lighttpd

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have this rule in my server:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)$" => "$0",
    "^/.*(\?.*)" => "/index.php$1",
    "" => "/index.php"
)
```

and it works as it should be... except for a little detail. If I add get info to the js or css files then it redirects the request to index.php. If I have this:

```
/css/main.css
```

it loads the css, but if I add:

```
/css/main.css?version=1234
```

Then it try to load `/index.php/main.css/?version=1234`

What its wrong with my rule?

Answer (score 1):

The rule `.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)$`, and specially the `$` at the end, says that the url **must** ends with one of the extension inside parenthesis.

If you remove the `$` at the end, it should works.

Or you can add a new rule that will be specific for css and/or js **with** a version parameter:

```
.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|)\?version\=[0-9]+$
```